# Install two different Spring Tool Suite (STS) on one Macbook

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I wanted to know if it is possible to install two different versions of STS on my mac. Is it gonna work separately fine or there will be some conflicts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Tool Suite is based on Eclipse. Your can use as many installations as you want

Comment: In other words, there is no installer. It is a self-contained standalone application.